# RestKit - Exclude attribute mapping with nil value from RKRequestDescriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

The problem is that I need to remove the attribute @"unitprice" entirely from the payload when the value is nil, but keep it in there if it has a value in the request. So the payload for OrderLine would look as follows accordingly: @{"id":@"orderlineId", @"unitprice":@"unitprice"} OR @{"id":@"orderlineId"} Please note that the mapping is a one-to-many relationship. Is it possible to do this? Your help is really appreciated thank you!
/*
 requestDescriptor
 */

```
+(RKObjectMapping*) getSalesOrderMapping:(RKRequestMethod)method {

RKEntityMapping *requestMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"SalesOrder"
                                                       inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
RKEntityMapping *orderLinesMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"OrderLine"
                                                         inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
requestMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"salesOrderId" ];
NSMutableDictionary *attributeMappings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                                                                                         @"id": @"salesOrderId",
                                                                                         }];
NSDictionary *orderLineAttributeMappings = @{
                                             @"id": @"orderlineId",
                                             @"unitprice": @"unitPrice"
                                             };

[orderLinesMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:orderLineAttributeMappings];
[requestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"lines"
                                                                                toKeyPath:@"salesOrderToOrderLines"
                                                                              withMapping:orderLinesMapping]];


return  requestMapping;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that `unitprice` is a 1:many relationship? Show the OrderLine.h contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to implement dynamic request descriptor with 1-to-many relationship. So I had to build NSMutableDictionary manually by checking against nil value and then add the properties with its values like the following

```
[objectManager postObject:nil
                    path:@"/salesorder"
              parameters:[self customSalesOrderRequestMapping]
                 success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {... }

 - (NSMutableDictionary *) customSalesOrderRequestMapping {

    customSalesOrderAttributeDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    if (selectedSalesOrder.salesOrderId) [customSalesOrderAttributeDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"id": selectedSalesOrder.salesOrderId}];

    if (selectedSalesOrder.salesOrderToOrderLines.count > 0) {

        NSMutableArray *orderLinesMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
         for (OrderLine *orderLine in selectedSalesOrder.salesOrderToOrderLines)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *orderLineMutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            if (orderLine.orderlineId) [orderLineMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"id": orderLine.orderlineId}];
            if (orderLine.unitPrice) [orderLineMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"unitprice": orderLine.unitPrice}];
            [orderLinesMutableArray addObject:orderLineMutableDictionary];
    }

    [customSalesOrderAttributeDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"lines": orderLinesMutableArray}];

  }
    return customSalesOrderAttributeDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes` to `NO` on the mapping. You shouldn't need 2 different mappings (unless you do want to include `nil` in the JSON for some attributes).

Comment: I have updated my question, as assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes doesn't exclude 'unitprice' attribute from the JSON when it is nil and include it when it has a value. The problem is with our API, when the 'unitprice' didn't get changed we should exclude it from the JSON mapping, so we assign nil to the 'unitprice' and then we want to write some logic for the RestKit to exclude nil values from the JSON mapping. So I think this is only possible by using dynamic mapping, am I right? Thanks

Comment: Setting `assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes` to `NO` should omit nil from the mapped result, did you try it and see otherwise? Show that test code.

Comment: I have added these two lines     responseMapping.assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
    orderLinesMapping.assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO; weird no luck, it does exclude the not mapped attributes but because 'unitprice' is mapped then it keep it with the value nil. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You're making a request so you apply it to the inverse mapping that you take.

Comment: unfortunately the problem is that I need to remove the attribute entirely from the payload when the value is nil, but keep it in there if it has a value in the request.  So the payload would look as follows accordingly:

@{"id":@"orderlineId", @"unitprice":@"unitprice"}

OR 

@{"id":@"orderlineId"}


Please note that the mapping is a one-to-many relationship.  Is it possible to do this?  Your help is really appreciated thank you!

Comment: Should not be the settings with assignsDefaultValueForMissingAttributes and assignsNilForMissingRelationships properties kept even if the inverse mapping is created. The flags are describing behavior of the mapping, not the mapping instance behavior.